# How do I alter the title of a menu link?

Tags: navigation

In my website, users can collect some 'points' over time. I have a top-bar menu with some links (e.g. "home", "profile", "logout"). I want to alter the menu item "profile" and add the number points owned by the current connected user.

I tried several hook, and I almost succeeded in getting what I wanted with `hook_link_alter()`.

```
function mycustommodule_link_alter(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['text'] == "profile") {
    // Do some work.
    $variables['text'] = $variables['text'] . " (you have $nb_points points)";
  }
}
```

I cleared the cache (with `drush cr`), and the menu item shows the value I want. But, if the value changes for some reason, it shows the old value. I must clear the cache all the times to update its value.

How can I avoid cleaning the cache to update the menu title all the times the points gained from the user change?

Comment: It sounds like you need custom plugin for this. Interesting question. Generally you should avoid implementing any old school hooks in D8. The question is how to alter menu title via custom plugin.

Comment: Is your menu in a block ? If that's the case maybe try to set the cache to 0 for that block

Comment: its a block created from the administration interface. I didn't access to cache configuration :)

Comment: I suggest you start with https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api , the     '#cache' => ['max-age' => 0], is not a solution. you need to create a dynamic menu link.

Comment: "the menu item shows the value I want"

Have you checked the menu with other user account? I suspect it is showing the same number of points for all users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest implementing a custom menu link plugin. The code below assumes your module name is *example*.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example\Plugin\Menu;

use Drupal\Core\Database\Connection;
use Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkDefault;
use Drupal\Core\Menu\StaticMenuLinkOverridesInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * A menu link that displays number of points.
 */
class ExampleMenuLink extends MenuLinkDefault {

  /**
   * The database connection.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection
   */
  protected $dbConnection;

  /**
   * Constructs a new points menu link.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Menu\StaticMenuLinkOverridesInterface $static_override
   *   The static override storage.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection $db_connection
   *   The database connection.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, StaticMenuLinkOverridesInterface $static_override, Connection $db_connection) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $static_override);
    $this->dbConnection = $db_connection;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('menu_link.static.overrides'),
      $container->get('database')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getTitle() {
    $count = $this->dbConnection->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {example_points}')->fetchField();
    return $this->t('You have (@count) points', ['@count' => $count]);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheTags() {
    // Invalidate these tags when number of points is changed.
    return ['example.points_count'];
  }

}
```

If you don't want to inject the database service the class would become much simpler.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example\Plugin\Menu;

use Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkDefault;
use Drupal\Core\Menu\StaticMenuLinkOverridesInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * A menu link that displays number of points.
 */
class ExampleMenuLink extends MenuLinkDefault {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getTitle() {
    $count = \Drupal::database()->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {example_points}')->fetchField();
    return $this->t('You have (@count) points', ['@count' => $count]);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheTags() {
    // Invalidate these tags when number of points is changed.
    return ['example.points_count'];
  }

}
```

Next you need to put the link definition into *example.links.menu.yml* file.

```
example.user_points:
  route_name: <front>
  menu_name: main
  class: Drupal\example\Plugin\Menu\ExampleMenuLink
  weight: 30
```

**The caching problem**

Whenever the number of points is changed the menu link cache should be invalidated as follows.

```
 \Drupal::service('cache_tags.invalidator')->invalidateTags(['example.points_count']);
```

You need to find out the right place for this. If the points managed by contributed module check the module API and pick up an appropriate hook (*hook_points_insert()*, *hook_points_delete()* and so on).

Since the number of points is calculated for each user account individually you may consider using per account cache tags (something like `['example.points_count.' . $uid]`). Therefore the cache will be preserved  for users with unchanged points.

---

To generate code for the Menu link plugin I used [Drupal Code Generator](https://github.com/Chi-teck/drupal-code-generator).

Comment: This answer is spot on (and more helpful than the current [official documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-menu-links). However, the yaml file should be named example.links.menu.yml, no **example.menu-links.yml**. After that, clear the cache and your menu item should appear.

Comment: Is this possible to override also the getRouteParameters() method? If no, how one can alter the route_parameters to be dynamic? In my case I have {user} in routing and menu link should provide the user ID dynamically as user ID of current user.

Comment: @Igal think it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. The menu items are cached, so it always shows the old value until you clear the cache. Alternative way is using `hook_page_attachments()`, attach points to drupalSettings.YOUR_MODULE_OR_THEME.YOUR_VARIABLE, and access them in JavaScript, and render in the browser.

Normal way is disabling cache for pages whenever the "profile" menu displays at site performance.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the cache for that menu in `hook_preprocess_menu()` by setting `$variables['#cache']['max-age']` to 0.